# How can I add Third party vendor JARS to my Mediation Project in WSO2 ESB

Tags: rest, wso2, wso2-esb

How can I add Third party vendor JARS to my Mediation Project in WSO2 ESB. I need to use the methods from the objects of these jars in my mediator during runtime..Please let me know your suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

You can put them inside `<ESB_HOME>/repository/components/lib` directory, and use them in your class mediator.